# get facebook comment count with jquery

Tags: jquery, facebook, facebook-fql

How would I use jQuery to get the comment count of a specific url, The url has comments added with facebook comments box

Also is there an option to get a combined comment count of all urls that start with the same domain?

Answer (score 0):

You can use simple a JSON request and pluck the comment count off of it

```
function getCommentNum() {
    $.getJSON("https://graph.facebook.com/[your facebook user id]_[story id of post]?callback=?", function(json) {
        alert(json.comments.count);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="aaa"></div>
function getFacebookCommentCount(url, callback) {
    $.getJSON('https://graph.facebook.com/?ids='+url, function(data) {
        if(url && url != '#' && url != '') {
           if(!data['error']) {
              callback(data[url]);
           }
        }
     });
}

getFacebookCommentCount('http://example.com/', function(callback) {
  $('.aaa').html(callback['comments']+'-'+callback['shares']);
});
```

test on: http://jsfiddle.net/rg2BU/
used on: http://www.xaluan.com